# Why does \b not interpreted as backslash in this regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

This is my code:

```
import re
string = "hello\bworld"
reg = r"\bhello\b"
print(re.findall(reg, string))
```

output is:

```
   ['hello']
```

But this doesn't make sense to me.
In the official python [documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) ***\b*** is described as the worst collision between python's and regex's escape squences:

> the worst collision between Python’s string literals and regular
> expression sequences. In Python’s string literals, \b is the backspace
> character, ASCII value 8. If you’re not using raw strings, then Python
> will convert the \b to a backspace, and your RE won’t match as you
> expect it to

In python **\b** is interpreted as a backspace character, so *string* will be translated into ***hellworld***.

```
print(string)
```

output is:

```
hellworld
```

While in regular expression **\b** is interpreted as a word boundary
So searching the pattern ***r"\bhello\b"*** in ***hellworld*** should theoretically yield 0 matches
Since there isn't any hello surrounded by word boundaries in ***hellworld***

I expected the result to be an empty list

Another way to look at is with this code:

```
import re
string = "hello\bworld"
reg = r"hellw"
print(re.findall(reg, string))
```

here the output is:

```
[]
```

Which again doesn't make sense to me since there **is** a hellw in string **string**
printing ***string*** proves it:

```
print(string)
hellw
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Printing doesn't show you what's actually there, it shows you _what the terminal renders_ the variable's contents as. `print(repr(string))` if you want to know what's actually there in an unambiguous form.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy for string="hello\bworld" ***print(repr(string))*** yields "hello\x08world". Still doesn't seem like a "\bhello\b" should be found in there

Comment: `'\x08'` is the same character as `'\b'`, just two different ways of writing it. And Barmar describes why `r'\b'` works as a regex operator here (matches at the start or end of a world, and `'\b'` or `'\x08'` isn't a character that can be considered to be part of the inside of a word, so encountering the backspace next to characters that _are_ word-legal means you're at a word boundary).

Comment: If that doesn't work as an explanation, describe _why_ (after reading the answers presently available on the question) you don't think `r'\bhello\b'` should match `'hello\x08world'` so I can clarify from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backspace doesn't modify the contents of the string, it just affects how the string is printed on a terminal. The string contains `o` followed by backspace. Since `o` is a word character and backspace is a non-word character there's a word break between them, so `\b` in the regexp matches there.

Comment: Hm - I think we answered within a second of each other; can't tiebreak on timing here. :)

Comment: It took me several readings of the question to finally figure out where he was going wrong. I kept posting comments address different, more common confusions.

Comment: Thank you for pin pointing that backspace itself is not a word character, which result with a word boundary between the backspace and the 'o'. that was the missing piece of the puzzle for me

Answer (score 2):

The translation from `'hello\bworld'` to `hellworld` isn't done by Python itself -- instead, it's done *by your terminal*. The word `hello` is printed, then the cursor moves left a space when the backspace is printed, and the `w` is printed over where the `o` used to be.

Because the actual string contains an extra character (the backspace) between `hello` and `world`, a search for `hellw` isn't expected to match, and a search for `hello` as a distinct word (read: not surrounded by other word-valid characters at the front or end) *is* expected to match.